# CSS flickering frame

Tags: css, css-animations

I need to 1-pixel-thick frame appeared and disappeared, but in my code it look like second frame appears instead first one disappears (or first one becoms thicker and darker), and only then do this both disappear.

```css
#bord1 {
  -webkit-animation: bord 2s linear infinite;
  animation: bord 2s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bord {
  50% {
    border: 1px solid red
  }
}

@keyframes bord {
  50% {
    border: 1px solid red
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bord1">10 000 000</div>
```

Comment: @doğukan oh thank you very much. Sorry that no immediately, I am no oft here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a initial transparent border

```css
#bord1 {
  animation: bord 2s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent; /* added */
}

@keyframes bord {
  50% {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bord1">10 000 000</div>
```